# Accessing Googles Book API via C++ and Qt

Tags: c++, json, api, qt, google-books

I like to get Information from the [Google Books API](https://developers.google.com/books/).

Therefore I need to perform a http request like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:3826615956 and retrieve an JSON formated document.

Then it's necessary to extract just some variables from the document. So My Questions are:

1. Is there any Class in Qt to Access JSON docs and/or to perform the http requests.
2. If not, how can I manage that with pure c++? Is there any similair example available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both parts are supported by Qt, or rather by Qt + third-party library:

For HTTP requests, use [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QNetworkAccessManager.html). The documentation gives some simple examples how to fire a request.

For Json with Qt4, you can use [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net), available under LGPL. (There will be Json support as part of Qt 5, see [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/json.html), but that's not there yet in Qt4)